# Can't call the return from a function

Tags: java, return

I've created the next code, but the return from normalizeText can't be called. Why is that?

```
public class crypto {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    String text = "Dit is een test";
    normalizeText(text);
    shiftAlphabet(normalizedText,-1);
    System.out.println("Dit is: " + normalizedText());
}

public static String normalizeText(String text){
    String normalizedText = text;
    text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    normalizedText= text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
    normalizedText= text.toUpperCase();
    return normalizedText;
}
```

Comment: because you don't call the method correctly, you need to pass an instance of String as parameter

Comment: What does `shiftAlphabet` do? Are you aware that Strings are immutable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the result of normalizeText to a variable.

```
String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);
shiftAlphabet(normalizedText,-1);
System.out.println("Dit is: " + normalizedText);
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't assign the result to you variable, try this :

```
 public static void main (String [] args) {
        String text = "Dit is een test";
        String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);
        shiftAlphabet(normalizedText,-1);
        System.out.println("Dit is: " + normalizedText);
    }

    public static String normalizeText(String text){
        String normalizedText = text;
        text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        normalizedText= text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
        normalizedText= text.toUpperCase();
        return normalizedText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
normalizeText(text)
```

to

```
String normalizedText = normalizeText(text)
```

Comment: While code only answer may be right, it is not always helpful. Please provide explanation to elaborate/

Comment: @Jeet sry, I wanted to add expalantions z but there was no stable internet connection and I couldn't do that. And now, there's a lot of other answers with good expalantions

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is:

```
public class crypto {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String text = "Dit is een test";
        String myNormalizedText = normalizeText(text);
        shiftAlphabet(myNormalizedText,-1);
        System.out.println("Dit is: " + myNormalizedText);
    }

    public static String normalizeText(String text){
        String normalizedText = text;
        text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        normalizedText= text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
        normalizedText= text.toUpperCase();
        return normalizedText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

how does your code even compile?

You are calling System.out.println("Dit is: " + normalizedText()); without a parameter. Your normalizedText() method needs a String. Do you have another normalizedText()-method defined, without parameters in the signature?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong from start to end. You are calling normalizeText method without assigning it to a variable. And then you try to call normalizeText() without parameters which is not defined.

Try :

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    String text = "Dit is een test";
    String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);
    System.out.println("Dit is: " + shiftAlphabet(normalizedText,-1));
}
```